# Improvements for this Rounding Method

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net

This is used to round to any desired quarter, half etc.

Is there any improvements that can be made for performance, unforeseen roundoff issues etc...?

```
//Equals 1.0
var test = RoundNearest(1.0000002, .5);
//Equals 1.5
var test2 = RoundNearest(1.3, .5);
//Equals 1.0
var test 3 = RoundNearest(1.0,.5) ;

private static double RoundNearest(double raw, double n)
{
    var r = Math.Round(raw, 1);
    if (!(Math.Abs(r % 1) <= double.Epsilon * 100))
    {
        return Math.Round(r * 1 / n) * n;
    }
    return r;
}
```

This started with me needing to round to the nearest half.

```
> Example: Step 1:  p = 1.2
>          Step 2:  p x 2 = 2.4
>          Step 3:  Normal Rounding p = 2
>          Step 4:  p/2 = 1
```

Then I wanted to try and extend that to be able to round the quarter, half... ETC.

This line is used to handle issues like 1.000005

```
var r = Math.Round(raw, 1);
```

This line is used to detect if the number is already a integer.  If so go ahead and return it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer

```
if (!(Math.Abs(r % 1) <= double.Epsilon * 100))
```

This will round 1.3 to 1.5 using .5 as the target

```
return Math.Round(r * 1 / n) * n;
```

Comment: I might be wrong but doing `Math.Round(raw/n, 1) * n` will do the same thing and it's easier

Comment: Can you explain what purpose of `r % 1` and `r * 1`?

Comment: @Maxim `r % 1` is a hacky way of writing `r - (long) r`, i.e., it gets the fractional part of `r`. (At least in C# and Java who have well defined modulo on floating point values)

Comment: As for `r * 1`, I'm pretty sure that's weird - one could get the same result as `r * 1 / n` from `r / n`

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Hmm, I didn't know about this trick to get fractional part. I've checked it in C# Interactive in VS and it really works. Thank you!

Comment: @Maxim, it's not really a trick - it's what in fact makes the most sense. Well, arguably `fractional(x) = x - floor(x)` (which is what essentially a cast to `long` does) matches more with the mathematical definition of `{x}` though.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Yes, but I always used long form `x - Math.Truncate(x)` :)

Comment: Do you expect this to work for fractions like 2/3, 4/5, etc. or is the expectation that they will be integer divisors of 1? If the former, then your 'near integer' check is probably wrong (i.e. what is the expected result of `RoundNearest(2.0, 0.8)`? what about `raw:2.1`?), and if the later, you can round only the truncated part and mitigate some large-value precision issues. You'll also need to consider inputs with `n>1`, (e.g. `n:100` find me the nearest 'hundred'), which your `near 1` check currently breaks.

Comment: Clarify the potential issues I brought up in my answer or I will vote to close.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I got pulled away with no internet access to reply.  The r % 1 is using the modulus operator to determine if a number is already a integer.  Updated my question.  This is the same as the Mod operator in vb.net.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/modulus-operator

Comment: @Visual Melon.  I am aiming for the later.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: VTC as code is broken.  roundNearest = RoundNearest(1.000005d, 000001d); return 1 and should return 1.000005.   1.000005 is not already and integer.  I tried to explain it to you.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @Paparazzi Can it be considered an edge case that is easy to miss? If so, then it's not necessarily off-topic.

Comment: @SimonForsberg It fails on a pretty big range. RoundNearest(1.03d, 0.05d); fails.  I used 1.000005d as an example as that number is used in the question.  If it does not get closed fine with me.  OP has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!(Math.Abs(r % 1) <= double.Epsilon * 100))
```

I think this is cleaner

```
if (Math.Abs(r % 1) > double.Epsilon * 100)
```

Not understanding what the `* 1` adds

Why are you lopping it down to 1 fraction digit before preforming the math?

This makes no sense to me `(r % 1)` is 0 or a number that does not approach double.Epsilon

```
private static double RoundNearest(double raw, double n)
{
    foreach (Double d in new List<double> { 1.01, 1.11, 1.22, 1.33, 1.44, 1.55, 1.66, 1.77, 1.88, 1.99 })
    {
        var rr = Math.Round(d, 1);
        Debug.WriteLine($"// {d} {rr} {rr % 1}");
    }
    // 1.01 1   0
    // 1.11 1.1 0.1
    // 1.22 1.2 0.2
    // 1.33 1.3 0.3
    // 1.44 1.4 0.4
    // 1.55 1.6 0.6
    // 1.66 1.7 0.7
    // 1.77 1.8 0.8
    // 1.88 1.9 0.9
    // 1.99 2   0

    var r = Math.Round(raw, 1);
    Debug.WriteLine(r % 1);
    if (!(Math.Abs(r % 1) > double.Epsilon * 100))
    {
        return Math.Round(r * 1 / n) * n;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to respond to your questions.  Thanks for the comments.